# O que fazer quando uma pergunta recebe uma resposta incorreta?

Tags: debate, respostas

Se uma pergunta receber uma resposta incorreta (até que com boa intenção) o que devo fazer? Qual o procedimento padrão para esse tipo de situação?

Comentei que isso não resolve o problema, e o autor respondeu prontamente e parece que ele verificou que está incorreta e desistiu de sua resposta.

Até aguardei para ver ser alguém comentava, ou dava downvote (se for o caso), mas nada aconteceu e a resposta está lá e não sei o que fazer, se dou downvote, sinalizo.

Então pesquisei aqui no meta e não encontrei nada referente a uma situação similar a essa. Qual o procedimento da comunidade em relação a uma situação como essa?

A pergunta e resposta que me refiro é [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31304/executar-query-que-concatene-parametros-p-no-firebird).

Desculpem se essa questão não se encaixa ao meta, ou se já há algo aqui que responda isso.

Comment: Se a resposta está errada, vote contra ela. Isso vai demonstrar para quem visitar a questão que deve tomar cuidado com ela. E sempre deixe um comentário dizendo que não funcionou e a mensagem de erro ou motivo. Se o usuário não melhorar ou remover a questão, ele está assumindo o risco de mais *downvotes*.

Comment: É basicamente o que o utluiz disse. Mas claro que você não é obrigado a votar contra, vote se quiser. Não adianta sinalizar, pois o máximo que os moderadores poderiam fazer seria excluir a resposta, o que não devemos fazer (excluir uma resposta errada é decisão do autor dela).

Comment: Então a ação cabível seria votar contra, se for o caso, e o autor que vai verificar se é possível recuperar ou se deseja excluir certo? Sinalizar não é o caminho com disse o @bfavaretto.

Comment: Acho que antes de dar um DOWN, temos que ter certeza de que a pergunta está clara o suficiente. Eu opto em emitir um aviso e se não ajustar a resposta acho que ai sim merece DOWN pela falta de compromisso.

Answer (score 16):

Como eu faço (geralmente):

- **Aviso o autor sobre o erro** em comentário, indicando o problema, e aguardo um tempo razoável.

  Exceto quando são aqueles autores que já são velhos conhecidos e ficam horas debatendo a "teoria quântica da reprodução das lagartas de peito rosado do Quênia" <sup>1</sup> para justificar a resposta, em vez de consertar o erro. Além deste caso, quando o erro é manifestamente gritante, onde se vê que o autor não teve nem a preocupação de entender o site ou de ler minimamente a pergunta, também não perco muito tempo avisando. Nestes casos, já pulo para a etapa seguinte:
- **Voto negativo**.

  Sempre bom lembrar que voto negativo não significa repreensão pessoal, e sim serve para **orientar a comunidade e futuros visitantes que há um problema ali**.

**Resumo:**

O "mecanismo padrão" é o voto negativo, mas aplicar uma dose de bom senso antes disso faz do site um lugar melhor, e ajuda o autor que tem boa vontade a melhorar sua postagem.

<sub>1. falando bobagens</sub>